# Git - How to update or remove "local out of date" copies of tracked remote branches?

Tags: git

When I run a `git remote show origin` I have a bunch of `local out of date` branches.

[image: local out of date]

**I don't care about these branches, all I want is to not have `local out of date` versions, either by getting them `up to date` or removing my local copy (while retaining the tracking of origin/branchName).**

I am not sure why I'm having such a difficult time figuring this one out. All my searches just turn up with people wanting to delete the remote branches or prune branches that no longer exist on remote. I thought `git pull --all` would be the solution, but that doesn't do anything for me.

Thanks all!

**EDIT:** Wow I'm an idiot, I was way overthinking it. Yes, thank you [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), your immediate answer is correct, all I wanted to do was delete the local branch.

```
git branch -d branchName
```

Ideally I was looking for a command to delete all `local out of date` branches in one line, but I guess I'll just have to make a short script for it. Here we go, technically all in one line:

```
git remote show origin | grep "local out of date" | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR: you probably just want to delete some of your branches

The full answer is a bit complex, in part because `git remote` does something no other Git command can do.  If you're not *using* a local branch name, though, you can simply delete it as a distraction.  The trick is knowing *when it is safe to delete*, although "when I'm not already using it and won't *be* using it" is always a good enough time.

Use `git branch -d branchname` to delete-with-checking, and `git branch -D branchname` to delete forcefully, i.e., without checking.  The "checking" that Git does is *different* from the checking that `git remote` does, so do not be too surprised if they do not agree.

Since (and including) Git version 2.3, you can spell this `git branch -d -f` or `git branch --delete --force`, the way nearly all other Git commands do it.  In older versions of Git you must use the uppercase `-D` to forcefully delete a branch name.

It might also be a good idea to stop using `git remote show origin` at all.

## Git terminology, or, why you can't find documentation

The Git terminology surrounding this sucks, to put it bluntly.  You will see the same words used in different combinations to mean different—sometimes *very* different, although usually at least a little bit related—things.  Git has:

- Remotes.  A *remote* is just a one-word name like `origin`.  A remote name supplies, at a minimum, a URL, so `origin` is short for `ssh://example.com/path/to/repository` or `https://...` or whatever.  A remote name also provides a prefix for "remote-tracking branches", which we have not defined just yet.

  Note that the existence of a remote name implies that there is some *other* Git, usually on another machine entirely, found via the URL.  That other Git repository has all of its own settings, quite independent from yours!  This will matter when we talk about remote-tracking branches.
- Branches.  The word *branch* is ambiguous in Git (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068543/what-exactly-do-we-mean-by-branch) for details), but here it means *branch name*.  These may also be called *local branches* to distinguish them from the other kind.  A branch name is just a short—well, usually short—name like `master` or `develop` or `machines/hal9000` or `users/dave` or `tasks/I_cant_do_that_dave`.  These names *can* have slashes, and the somewhat complicated rules about using slashes in them can mostly be ignored.

  A branch name points to *one specific commit*, which Git calls the *tip* commit of that branch.  Each commit in any Git repository "points back" to earlier commits, too.  More precisely, a commit points to its *parent* commit, or for merges, to its (multiple) parents.  This forms a backwards chain, so that by starting from the tip of the branch, Git can find all the rest of the commits that are on that branch.

  (As an important side effect, this means many commits are on *more than one* branch.  That does not matter here, but it is one of the keys to understanding Git's branches.)

  Beware of names that start with `origin/` or any other remote-name, though, because those usually refer to...
- *Remote-tracking branches*.  These show up as names like `origin/master`.  The *function* of a remote-tracking branch is to let your Git remember, for you, what your Git saw the last time it talked to that *other* Git, over on the remote.  The points of contact here are `git fetch`, which brings stuff from the remote Git to your Git, and `git push`, which sends things from your Git to the remote Git along with a request that the remote Git accept them.  The details matter somewhat but we'll leave that for later.  Just note that `git remote` not only *can*, but usually *does*, contact the other Git—but then it *immediately forgets everything it learned*, unlike `git fetch`.

Git always keeps remote-tracking branches *completely separate* from local branch names, so that you *can* have a local branch named `origin/master` at the same time that you have a remote-tracking branch named `origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>  But don't do that: it's too confusing.

So far so good, except for the rather verbose name *remote-tracking branch*.  Some people try to shorten it to "remote branch", but this is a bad idea, because ... well, there's that other Git, the one over on `origin`.  It's the *remote Git* (not a great name but what else will we call it?).  It *is* a Git repository, so it has branches.  What are we going to call them?  The obvious answer is "remote branches", or maybe "branches on the remote".  (Git does not really have a proper name for these.)

The purpose of your remote-tracking branches is to keep track of these "on-the-remote branches".  Your remote-tracking branches are, however, still *yours*: they live in your repository, and you can update them yourself if you really insist (but you should just let your Git do it automatically).  This is also where `git fetch --prune remotename` and `git remote prune remotename` and `git remote update --prune remotename` come in.  The prune options—which *should* all be the same, but have had slightly different bugs in different Git versions—are instructions to your Git:  "When you fetch from that other Git, find out what branches *it* has, and for any of *my* remote-tracking branches that no longer match a branch-on-the-remote, delete it automatically."

While `git fetch` updates *all* your remote-tracking branches for you, `git push` does not.  Instead, if you are pushing your `master` to `origin` and asking *their* Git to update *their* master, *your* Git will then take the opportunity to update *your* `origin/master`.  Your Git does not, during this push transaction, bother to find and save information on any of their other branches.  (There's no important idea behind this, it's just Git's historical behavior, with no strong reason to change it either.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has specific (and somewhat complicated) rules to pick which one you mean, in case of ambiguity.  If you get into this situation, you can use the "full names" for each *kind* of branch to tell them apart: a local branch's full name always starts with `refs/heads/`, while a remote-tracking branch's full name always starts with `refs/remotes/` followed by the name of the remote.

Thus, `origin/master` is short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`, i.e., a remote-tracking branch.

An accidental local branch with the same name is really `refs/heads/origin/master`.

If both exist, which one does `origin/master` actually use?  The answer for most Git commands is in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), but [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) behaves differently.  Just delete the bad local-branch-name.  It's *way* too confusing.

---

#### Summary so far

A *branch name* is your own name, like `master`.  This points to a *tip commit*.

A *remote* is just a name like `origin`.

A *remote-tracking branch* is *your* name, like `origin/master`, for your Git's memory of a name like `master` *as last seen on the remote*.  Running `git fetch` updates these, and adding `--prune` cleans up leftovers of these.  A successful `git push` updates your remote-tracking branch that corresponds to each successfully-pushed branch.

Now it gets bad. :-)

#### "Tracking" is not like remote-tracking branches, but usually *uses* them

In Git, you can set any branch—i.e., any ordinary local branch name—to "track" one, and only one, other branch.  If local branch *L* is tracking remote-tracking branch *R*, we also say, at least in newer Git documentation, that *R* is *L*'s *upstream*.  For generality, though, and/or just to be more confusing and Gitty, Git lets you track another *local* branch instead.  So *L* might track *U*, which is also local, and then *U* is *L*'s upstream.

The only really critical thing is to realize that each of your local names, like `master` and `develop`, has either *no* upstream, or *one* upstream.  Most often, local branches have an upstream that is a remote-tracking branch, with the remote-tracking branch having much the same name as the local branch, but with the remote's name added.  Hence `master` has `origin/master` as its upstream.

Again, "has as its upstream" is the newfangled longer—but (we hope) less confusing—way to say "tracks".  The problem with the phrase "master tracks origin/master" is that origin/master is already a remote-tracking branch.  Remote-tracking branches *don't* have upstreams, so now we would have to claim that origin/master doesn't "track" anything, even though it's a "remote-tracking branch"!  (Yuck!  See why I say the terminology is terrible?  Maybe it would help if `origin/master` were called a "memory name" or something, but it's not.)

#### What good is having an upstream anyway?

The full answer is a bit long and complicated, but the short version is: this is how Git can say:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 286 commits, ...
```

and the like, and also how you can run `git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, and/or `git push` without spelling out *where to fetch from*, *what to merge or rebase-upon*, and *where to push*.  That's the main reason to set an upstream: it automates a bunch of stuff for you and makes `git status` (and `git branch -v`, in modern Gits) much more informative.

Several things set upstreams automatically.  The key one is that if you have a remote-tracking branch like `origin/develop`, *and* you don't *already* have a *local* branch named `develop`, you can just run:

```
git checkout develop
```

and your Git will discover that there is an `origin/develop` and *create* a new local name `develop` for you, with it set to "track"—i.e., have as its upstream—`origin/develop`.

Totally-new branches, that you have never pushed anywhere, generally *won't* have an upstream.  The "why not" is simple enough: the correct upstream for `newbranch` would be `origin/newbranch`.  But if you just created `newbranch` yourself, there *is no `newbranch` on the Git at `origin`*, so there can't be an `origin/newbranch` in your own Git repository either.  There's no remote-tracking branch to *set* as the upstream yet!  This is where `git push -u` comes in, as it means "push, then automatically set as upstream if the push works, since that also creates the remote-tracking branch if needed."

#### Pushing is not quite symmetric with fetching

When you `git fetch`, your Git calls up the remote's Git, probably over the Internet-phone.  Your Git gets a list of their branches and such, and then brings things over as needed—and then it *renames* their branches, making them into your *remote-tracking branches*.  Since your remote-tracking branches have, as a dedicated function, "remember what you saw on the remote", this is always a good thing to do, and modern Gits just always do it.<sup>2</sup>

When you `git push`, your Git calls up the remote's Git, sends them stuff, and *asks* them (politely, unless you use `--force`: then it asks a bit rudely) to set *their* branch to refer to the same commit as *your* branch.  You can control the precise form of asking with a *refspec*, which I won't cover in detail here, but normally their branch name is the *same* as your branch name.  That is, you `git push origin master:master` to ask them to set *their* master to match *your* master exactly.

**There is no automatic renaming here.**  This is why, for your push to succeed, ***your* branch must normally first be caught up with *their* branch.**  Generally, you do this by merging or rebasing.  That's all *your* responsibility: the remote Git won't do any merging.  It just either *accepts* your request, or *rejects* it.  The default rule, if you do not use `--force` or equivalent, is to accept your push update **if and only if their *old* tip commit is an ancestor of the *new* tip you are asking them to set.**

Moving a branch name from an old tip to a new tip, such that the new tip commit "contains" the old tip commit, is called a **fast-forward**.  This will be a key phrase later.  The test: "is changing from hash *X* to hash *Y* a fast-forward?" is *the same* test as: "is *X* an ancestor of *Y*?"

---

<sup>2</sup>Since Git version 1.8.4, anyway; and this also glosses over any configured `fetch` refspecs.  Older versions of Git are ... less helpful.

---

#### Summary the second

If your (local) branch *L* has (your) remote-tracking branch *R* set as its upstream, you get a bunch of nice automation.  You *do* have to run `git fetch` to get *R* updated: your Git calls up the remote's Git and updates all your remote-tracking branches, and now your Git can compare your *L* to your *R*, which is now in sync with their branch (probably named *L* on their end, but that's in *their* repository, so it's their responsibility, not yours).

Likewise, when your *L* has (your) *R* as its upstream, you can run `git push` and your Git figures out what to ask their Git to do.  For historical reasons, this is highly configurable, and versions of Git *before* Git 2.0 do something different by default, but since 2.0, the default action is simple (and is even called `simple`): your Git pushes your *L* to their branch that is also called *L*.  Their branch is probably named *L*, but let's just call it *B*, to tell them apart.  Your push will generally succeed only if your update to their *B* is a fast-forward.

## `git remote` is very different

Running `git remote show origin` blows much of the above right out of the water.

So why did we discuss it all?  Well, mainly because it's the *much more normal* way to work with Git.  All the documentation out there mostly talks about using it, and the words in that documentation are this confusing mishmash of: "branch" "tracks" / "has as upstream" "remote-tracking branch" (on the "remote", where it's named "branch").  It's important to realize that all these words have specific technical definitions ... *and* that many of them can just get blown away when you use `git remote`.  It's also useful because "local out of date", the message you are asking about, has a very specific meaning that ties in with `git push`, and we needed a lot of clarity about what `git push` does, vs what `git fetch` does, which means we needed a lot about remotes too.

What `git remote show remotename` normally does—you *can* tell it *not* to—is to call up the remote, just like `git fetch` or `git push` would.  This means it gets an instantaneous, right-now picture, just like `git fetch` or `git push` would.  It then tells you what `git fetch` right now, or `git push` right now, would do or try to do.

If their Git—the Git on the remote—has a branch named *B*, *your* Git would likely fetch it into *your* `origin/B`.  So your `git remote show origin` says:

```
Remote branches:
  master tracked
```

which essentially means "I would fetch `master` and call it `origin/master`".  (I would argue that this is poorly phrased; but it's like this for historical reasons.)

Meanwhile, if you have a local branch named *L*, that local branch may be set to "track" (i.e., may have as an upstream) one of the branches your `git fetch` would bring over from the remote and rename.  For instance, your Git would bring over *their* `master` and call it `origin/master`, and *your* `master` might then be behind their master, or ahead of their master, or anyway need merging or rebasing.  You would then merge or rebase using your `origin/master`, which they call `master`.  So your `git remote show origin` says:

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  master    merges with remote master
```

(There are some historical mistakes preserved here as well, which is why the phrasing is the way it is.  This also refers to `git pull`, which I argue no beginner should use.)

Meanwhile, your `master` may not match their `master`, so that if you ran `git push`, your Git would ask their Git to change their `master` to match yours.  Your `git remote show origin` tells you *this* by saying:

```
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

or:

```
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

This last message is not as useful as it might seem, since by the time you actually run `git push`, *their* Git may have changed.  Still, let's look at precisely what it means.

As we noted briefly above, when talking about `git push`, you *can* push your local branch—which we're calling *L* here—to a *different name* in their Git repository; so let's continue to call theirs *B* here.  In any case, as we also noted, when you `git push`, you will send them commits if needed, then ask them to set *their* branch—their *B*—to point to *one specific commit*: the tip commit of your *L*.

Because your Git starts by asking their Git about all its branches, your Git can tell which commit hash-ID their *B* names.  Any commits you will send their Git, ending with the tip of your *L*, will be all-new to them.  But your Git can *also* tell whether *their* tip commit—their *B*—is "new to you", because you either have that commit now, or you don't.

If you *do* already have their *B*, your Git can tell whether that commit is an ancestor of your (tip-commit-of) *L*.  If you *don't* have it, then by definition, it's *not* an ancestor of *L*,<sup>3</sup> and the push will be rejected.  You will need to fetch, then merge or rebase.  Even if you *do* have it, it's possible that *B* is not an ancestor of *L*—and your push will be rejected, and you must merge or rebase.  So that's what "local out of date" means: you may need to fetch—you might as well just do it since it's always safe—and then you definitely need to merge or rebase, to be able to push politely.

**If you don't intend to push this particular branch**, this information is useless.  Even if you *do* intend to push, the information becomes stale, potentially very quickly: as soon as *someone else* pushes, what your `git remote show origin` showed is out of date.

In any case, though, that's what "fast-forwardable" means: you can try your push, and if it fails, you will need to fetch, then merge or rebase.  "Local out of date" means you will need to fetch, then merge or rebase, and then try to push.  Why not just fetch, then merge or rebase if needed, then try to push?  *What did you gain by running `git remote show origin`?*

---

<sup>3</sup>The proof for this falls apart in the presence of a shallow repository.  With shallow repositories, `git remote show origin` may simply lie to you.

---

## Armed with 10k words, now back to the original question

> I don't care about these branches, all I want is to not have local out of date versions, either by getting them up to date or removing my local copy (while retaining the tracking of origin/branchName).

The phrase "the tracking of `origin/branchName`" is kind of a stumbling block here for me.  All the `origin/branchName`s will get updated on `git fetch` whether or not you have a local branch.  The local branch will "track" (have as an upstream) `origin/branchName` if you create it with the automatic-upstream method, which is the easy way.  So I think the answer here is "just delete the local branches".